# jQuery: post a multidimensional array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, multidimensional-array

**I am learning how to use jQuery, $.post and php. (I am not a pro like you guys)**

I want to send a multidimensional array to php.
My array looks something like this:

```
var item= new Array();
item[0] = ["Object", "Value"];
item[1] = ["id", "x"];
item[2] = ["status", "y"];
item[3] = ["date", "z"];
etc...
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
//AJAX
$("#add").click(function()
{
$.post( 'ajax_new.php' ,
    {
    item : item
    },

    function(data)
    {
    alert( data );
    } //end: if:else

); //END:$.post
}); //END:ajax
```

Also, after posting the array, how do I handle it in php?
Like this?:

```
<?
$id = $_POST['item'][1][1];
echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: And what's the problem? How is jQuery sending the data and how do you want it to be sent? How do you expect us to be able to help you if you don't even state the result you want to get?

Comment: And where are you having trouble?  Can you run print_r($_POST["item"]); from the PHP script ajax_new.php and show us what you're getting from the request?

Comment: this works if you're flexible with your own data structure http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: Can you change the data structure? I would suggest an object: `var items = { Object: "Value", id: "x",...}` which then can be accessed with `$_POST['id']`, etc.

Comment: I do not know how to send an array in the first place, let alone a multidimensional array. ALSO, after sending the stuff, I do not know how to access the info in php.

Comment: You should really be using json or xml to send structured data between two different languages. Look for Array to JSON scripts and use json_decode() in php.

Comment: I do not know what JSON is. Can someone PLEASE give me some code samples so I my understand what you guys are talking about?

Comment: It turns out that, with this current code, AJAX is sending the multidimensional array to PHP! Now I need to figure out how to send a PHP array back to AJAX

Answer (score 3):

I use to convert collected data to JSON before send it to the server.
http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: That would be my approach - see http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/ for help. The array converts readily to JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely convert it to JSON  object or either use JSON object instead of an array.